# Devise account confirmation link does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I updated Devise gem from 2.2.3 -> 3.2. everything else works fine but Account confirmation link sent as email does not work fine.

When User click on that link it always ask the user to resend confirmation link and it never confirms the account.

I checked the stored confirmation token in User table and the confirmation token sent as email both are same but still does not work.

Here is my mailer code for account confirmation.

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults)  you need to change your Devise mailer to use `@token` instead of the old `@resource.confirmation_token`.

This should fix any token-based confirmation problems you're having. This is likely to fix any unlock or reset password token problems as well. Here is your mailer updated code

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token) %></p>
```

Comment: this worked thanks. I was searching for this problem whole day